# custom iterator method not working in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem when i want use my custom iterator method.

here is working example with array.map method  https://jsfiddle.net/p92ns6w6/

```
// working
var Hello = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            cols: [
                {a: 1, b:1},
                {a: 2, b:2},
                {a: 3, b:3},
            ]
        };
    },


    render: function() {
        return <div>{
            this.state.cols.map(function(col, index){
                return <p key={index} >{col.a}</p>
            })
        }</div>;
    }
});
```

this is not working https://jsfiddle.net/319gq7x1/

```
var CustomColsClass = function(cols){

    var _cols = cols

    return {
        each: function(fn){
            _cols.map(function(col, index){
                fn(col, index)
            })
        }
    }
}





var Hello = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            cols: new CustomColsClass(
                [
                    {a: 1, b:1},
                    {a: 2, b:2},
                    {a: 3, b:3},
                ]
            )
        };
    },


    render: function() {
        return <div>{
            this.state.cols.each(function(col, index){
                console.log(index)
                return <p key={index} >{col.a}</p>
            })
        }</div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is what you are trying to do, is almost correct except for the fact that,

you are not returning from your custom defined `each` function and you don't need to specify the `callback` in the return, that is taken care of by the function that you pass

One more thing, since `CustomColsClass` is a function, you can directly call it instead of specifying it with `new` keyword

You code will look like

```
var CustomColsClass = function(cols){

    var _cols = cols

    return {
        each: function(fn){
            console.log('map')
           return  _cols.map(fn)
        }
    }
}





var Hello = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            cols: CustomColsClass(
                [
                    {a: 1, b:1},
                    {a: 2, b:2},
                    {a: 3, b:3},
                ]
            )
        };
    },


    render: function() {
        return <div>{
            this.state.cols.each(function(col, index){
                console.log(index)
                return <p key={index} >{col.a}</p>
            })
        }</div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Working **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/319gq7x1/2/)**

Comment: i think we dont need return here, because your code works without returns too. Actually i want to do here not passing exactly col in callback function. For example [https://jsfiddle.net/eeLa0gwr/](https://jsfiddle.net/eeLa0gwr/)

Comment: It doesn't return the map output without `return  _cols.map(fn)`. And what is that you want

Comment: Thanks for help )

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`map`** js function directly in **JSX** like below example.

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      cols: [{
          a: 1,
          b: 1
        },
        {
          a: 2,
          b: 2
        },
        {
          a: 3,
          b: 3
        },
      ]
    };
  },


  render: function() {
    return <div> {
      this.state.cols.map(function(col, index) {
        return <p key={index + 1}>{col.a}</p>
      })
    } </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name = "World" /> ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: The OP is not actually trying to do that and has specifed that the map method works but actually wants to implement a custom factory for it.